# Intent pick Image From Camera compressed or with lower resolution or dimension

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview

I'm using an intent to get an image from Camera and then I should use the data returned from intent in my Activity to display the image in an ImageView.

I want to ask if I can ask to the system to get a lower resolution or dimension image adding to the intent some putExtra(..., ...) options, so I can avoid to compress bitmap and implement all the code (I'm sure system knows better than me how to do :) ).

I hope my request is clear and someone could help me!

Sorry for my english - Regards from Italy

Answer (score 2):

You can get a thumbnail of the image taken by using `data.getExtras().get("data");`:

```
final static int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1; // any int value you want

Intent mCameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(mCameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST:

                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                // your ImageView
                photoImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is an useful information; what about if I want to specify size in pixel of my image (for example i want to ask for an 800 X 600 image)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't ask the camera to do this unfortunately.  You have to get the bitmap and then sort it out yourself.  See http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html